Constraint formulation
Let $P$ be the set of periods, with $y_p$ as a binary variable, and $w_{p}^{t}$ as a binary variable that links period $p$ with period $t$, where $p, t \in P$, and $t = p +2$.
The constraint I am attempting to formulate can be described as following:

if $ y_p = 0$, then $w_{p}^{t} = w_{p}^{t+1}= \dots = w_{p}^{|P|} =  0$
if $y_p = 1 $, then $w_{p}^{t} = w_{p}^{t+1} = \dots = w_{p}^{|P|} = 1$
if $y_p = 1$ and $y_h = 1$ where $p < h$, then:

$w_{p}^{t} = w_{p}^{t+1} = \dots = w_{p}^{h-1} = 1$
$w_{p}^{h} = w_{p}^{h+1} = \dots = w_{p}^{|P|} = 0$
$w_{h}^{t} = w_{h}^{t+1} = \dots = w_{h}^{|P|} = 1$



In other words,if $y_p= 1$ and $y_h=1$, I want to activate $w_{p}^{t}$ from period $p+2$ to period $h-1$, deactivate from period $h$ to the last period, and activate $w_{h}^{t}$ from period $h+2$ to the last period.
For example, for $P=\{1,\dots,10\}$ and $y_3 = 1$ and $y_7 = 1$ the values for $w_{p}^{t}$ should be as follows:



var
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10




$y_p$
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
0






$w_p^{t}$
$t=$ 3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10




$p=1$
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


$p=2$
-
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


$p=3$
-
-
$w_{3}^{5}=$ 1
$w_{3}^{6}=$1
0
0
0
0


$p=4$
-
-
-
0
0
0
0
0


$p=5$
-
-
-
-
0
0
0
0


$p=6$
-
-
-
-
-
0
0
0


$p=7$
-
-
-
-
-
-
$w_{7}^{9}=$1
$w_{7}^{10}=$ 1


$p=8$
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
0



It is straightforward to enforce $w_{p}^{t}$ to 0 if $y_p = 0$. However, I can't figure out how to enforce the $w$ variables to be 1, especially when more than one $y$ variable is activated.
What I tried is for every tuple $(p,t)$:
$(y_p - y_t) \leq w_{p}^{t},\forall p,t \in P, t\geq 2$
this works if only one $y$ variable is activated, otherwise it's not valid since in our example $y_3 - y_8 \leq w_{3}^{8} = 1 - 0 \leq w_{3}^{8}$, which is wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Your first two rules contradict the third one.  Also, do you have any restriction like $\sum_{p\in P} y_p=2$?

No restrictions on the number of $y_p$ that can be activated. The only restriction is that if $y_p = 1$,then the first period on which $y$ can be activated or not is $h=p+3$.  These are actually the rules I wish to enforce: (1) if no $y$ is activated, then all $w =0$; (2) if one $y_p =1$ then all $w_{p}^{t} = 1$ for $p+2 \leq t \leq |P|$; (3) if two or more $y_p=1$, i.e. $p,h,j : p < h < j$, I want to enforce $w_{p}^{t} = 1$ for $p+2 \leq t \leq h-1$, $w_{h}^{t} = 1$ for $h+2 \leq t \leq j-1$ and $w_{j}^{t} = 1$ for $j+2 \leq t \leq |P|$, with all other $w$ being 0.

I am not very fluent with LaTeX. So, bear with my simple notations.
As I understand, you are trying to track a pattern between two time events. In other words, two time points $p_1,p_2$ where $y(p_1) = 1$ and $y(p_2) = 1$. And, for any time point $t$, you need to know the latest time $p$ when $y(p) = 1$, and thus $w(p,t)=1$.
I did a similar formulation recently. I started with a variable w similar to yours, but later found the following representation easier to implement. Instead of point variables, I defined pattern variables.
Define pattern variables: $X(p_1,p_2)$ such that

There is an event at $p_1$ and $p_2$. Or, $y(p_1)=1, y(p_2)=1$
There is no event between $p_1$ and $p_2$. Or $y(p)=0$, if $p1<p<p2$

To enforce the relationship, you need to add these constraints.

$y(p) \leq \displaystyle\sum_{k>p} X(p,k), \forall p$ // -- at least one pattern for each start
$X(p,k) \leq y(p), \forall p,k$ // -- pattern start
$X(k,p) \leq y(p), \forall p,k$ // -- pattern end

To avoid overlap in patterns (and ensure only one pattern is active at a time)

For any day $p^\prime$, where $p^\prime\geq p$ and $p^\prime<p+k, \sum X(p,p+k) \leq 1$

To ensure that an event last at least 2 days (which seems in your case), we can also add

$y(p)+y(p+1) \leq 1$, for any $p$

Now, To get $w(p,k)$ from $X$ pattern, you can do the following:

$w(p,k) = \displaystyle\sum_{p+2\leq k<p^\prime} X(p,p^\prime)$ for any $p,k$


It looks like your desired rules can all be captured by the following, where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are binary decision variables.

To enforce $x=0 \implies y=0$, rewrite the logical proposition $\lnot x \implies \lnot y$ in conjunctive normal form as $x \lor \lnot y$, which immediately yields linear constraint $x+(1-y) \ge 1$, which simplifies to $$x \ge y.\tag1\label1$$

To enforce $x=1 \implies y=1$, rewrite the logical proposition $x \implies y$ in conjunctive normal form as $\lnot x \lor y$, which immediately yields linear constraint $(1-x)+y \ge 1$, which simplifies to $$y \ge x.\tag2\label2$$  Alternatively, replace $x$ and $y$ with their complements $1-x$ and $1-y$ in \eqref{1}.  Alternatively, rewrite as the contrapositive $y=0 \implies x=0$ and interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$ in \eqref{1}.

To enforce $(x=1 \land y=1) \implies z=1$, rewrite the logical proposition $(x \land y) \implies z$ in conjunctive normal form as $\lnot x \lor \lnot y \lor z$, which immediately yields linear constraint $(1-x)+(1-y)+z \ge 1$, which simplifies to $$x+y-z \le 1.\tag3\label3$$

To enforce $(x=1 \land y=1) \implies z=0$, rewrite the logical proposition $(x \land y) \implies \lnot z$ in conjunctive normal form as $\lnot x \lor \lnot y \lor \lnot z$, which immediately yields linear constraint $(1-x)+(1-y)+(1-z) \ge 1$, which simplifies to $$x+y+z \le 2.\tag4\label4$$  Alternatively, replace $z$ with its complement $1-z$ in \eqref{3}.



$w_{p}^{t} \le y_{p} \quad \forall p, t$
$y_{p} \le w_{p}^{t} + \sum_p y_p - 1 \quad \forall t \in \{p+2,...,P \}$
$ \sum_p y_{p} + y_p - 2\le w_{p}^t + w_{h}^s + w_{j}^{k}\quad t \in \{p+2,...,h-1 \}, s \in \{h+2,...,j-1 \}$

You have $y_p$ and $\sum_p y_p$ in the same constraint.
